# docker phppyadmin container Access denied for user 'root'

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I have installed docker on **digitalocean** droplet successfully and below shows my **docker-compose.yml** configurations:

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_pass
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root_pass
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql:db
    environment: 
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_pass
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
```

And once I up the docker services everything works fine as you can see by below screen capture.
[image]

And I can access my mysql database inside terminal perfectly with my user credentials.

[image]

But the problem is when I try to access phpmyadmin with `droplet_ip:8080` its says:

```
 #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: YES)
```

And here I used same username (root) password (root_pass) as well.

Any suggestions regarding this problem would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: One thing to check: is your MySQL service listening on `ADDR_ANY` or just the localhost?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me

```
version: '3.1'
volumes:
  mysql-volume:

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
     - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
     MYSQL_DATABASE: db
     MYSQL_USER: user
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: supersecret

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: supersecret
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

don't mix up root user and MySQL user. In my example above I use the MySQL user to login with phpadmin. if you want to login using your root user you don't have to specify MySQL user and it will look like this (you don't need to specify a user for phpmyadmin because it's always root):

```
version: '3.1'
volumes:
  mysql-volume:

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
     - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
     MYSQL_DATABASE: db

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Also very important, remove your mysql volume when you want to recreate the whole setup. (`docker volume rm ..`). Because maybe your mysql is started with the same volume again after making changes.

Comment: Yes. Thank you @Ivthillo . It did work for me. I did not know about `volume  rm ..` commands . (y)

Comment: Another way to reset volumes related to current docker-compose.yml is `docker-compose rm -v`

Comment: Thanks, now work because  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
 of my mysql need be equals phpmyadmin container MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:

Answer (score 0):

I got the access denied error because I had a dollar sign in my password, which the docker compose file parses as variable substitution (I've only seen the `${}` syntax) on [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) page you will read "Both `$VARIABLE` and `${VARIABLE}` syntax are supported."

Therefore if I had for example this as my database password in the docker compose `file: hello$world`, the world variable would get substituted, of course I don't have a 'world' variable, the password that would be set in that case would be `hello`, so without knowing the docker compose syntax you would be trying to log in with `hello$world`, and you'd be denied access.